# Win32, Resource file, loading into memory

Tags: winapi

This is my `test.rc` file:

```
shader.hlsl shaders "HLSL\\shader.hlsl"
```

I know it doesn't look like usual rc file but whe I use function like this.

```
D3DX11CompileFromResource(handle, L"shader.hlsl", NULL, NULL, NULL, "VS", "vs_4_0", 0, 0, NULL, &s, &err, &hr);
```

It works perfectly, but I want to load this file into memory. Tell me please how to do it, because I'm lack of ideas now. I tried with something like that.

```
HRSRC hSrc = FindResource(GetModuleHandle(0), L"shader.hlsl", L"shaders");
```

but without success.

#### EDIT:

`FindResource()` returns NULL!

Comment: Pretty fishy that you have a decent *handle* for the D3DX11CompileFromResource() call but not for the FindResource() call.

Comment: Why do you insist on using a resource file with a non-standard format? Just because it works one time doesn't mean it's correct. And, uh, you're not having much luck with it the way you're doing it.

Comment: Because it's not up to me how it is arranged.

Comment: @CodyGray There is nothing wrong with custom resource types. That's what the type identifier is for.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track: You need to use a sequence of `FindResource` / `LoadResource` / `LockResource` :

```
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
HRSRC hRes = FindResource(hModule, L"shader.hlsl", L"shaders"); 
HGLOBAL hMem = LoadResource(hModule, hRes);
LPVOID lpResource = LockResource(hMem);

DWORD size = SizeofResource(hModule, hRes);
```

`lpResource` is a pointer to your resource. `size` is the size in bytes of the memory block. Of course, don't forget to call `FreeResource(hMem)` when you're done.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I've forgotten about most important thing: FindResource() returns NULL

Comment: FreeResource function is obsolete: it is not necessary to free the resources loaded using LoadResource. Ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648044(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Problem partially solved. In fact, I had a problem with resources of type "rcdata", not "shaders". I put the second as an example but didn't check it (I'm really sorry, that I wasted your time). Seems like every type name except "rcdata" works. But why...?

**EDIT:**
Problem fully solved. I just need to use RT_RCDATA as type name. Seems like "rcdata" type is a standard name.